# Derived mode without merging keymap

Tags: major-mode, keymap, derived-mode

It seems that when using `define-derived-mode`, the new mode's keymap is merged with that of the parent mode. Is there a way to avoid this? That is, to inherit font-lock, etc. from the parent mode, but have a completely new keymap.

E.g.

```el
(defvar foo-mode-map
  (let ((map (copy-keymap special-mode-map)))
    (define-key map (kbd "n") #'next-line)
    (define-key map (kbd "p") #'previous-line)
    map)
  "Keymap for foo-mode.")

(define-derived-mode foo-mode java-mode "Foo"
  "Major mode derived from `java-mode'.

\\{foo-mode-map}")
```

I'd like `foo-mode` to use `foo-mode-map` without any key sequences from `java-mode-map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual [(elisp) Derived Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html), `define-derived-mode` defines keymaps using the following rules:

> The new mode has its own sparse keymap, named ‘VARIANT-map’.
>             ‘define-derived-mode’ makes the parent mode’s keymap the
>             parent of the new map, **unless ‘VARIANT-map’ is already set and
>             already has a parent**.

You've used `copy-keymap` to create your keymap, and this doesn't set a parent keymap. If you do that explicitly, your new keymap won't inherit from java-mode:

```el
(defvar foo-mode-map
  (let ((map (copy-keymap special-mode-map)))
    (define-key map (kbd "n") #'next-line)
    (define-key map (kbd "p") #'previous-line)
     ;; Set parent map for foo-mode-map:
    (set-keymap-parent map special-mode-map)
     map)
  "Keymap for foo-mode.")

(define-derived-mode foo-mode java-mode "Foo"
  "Major mode derived from `java-mode'.

\\{foo-mode-map}")
```

Comment: Great, this works, though I'd do the `set-keymap-parent` inside of the `defvar` to keep everything together.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.

Comment: Don't use `copy-keymap` (for the same reason copy&paste of code is a bad idea).  Instead do: `(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))) (set-keymap-parent map special-mode-map) ...)`.

Comment: Is there a way to derive all the keys from major mode and not define a particular key from major in the minor mode? Fall back to, what is defined by users initially globally?